# How can I control which form is submitted when the user presses enter, based on which form the mouse is positioned over?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, mouseevent, keyevent

I have three forms on a page.  Each form has a username and password fields, and a checkbox.  Detecting when the user presses enter and to submit the appropriate form is not a problem:

```
$("input[type='text'], input[type='password'], input[type='checkbox']").keypress(function(event) {
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    }
});
```

However, the problem is if the checkbox is not selected, pressing enter won't submit the form.  My solution: If the mouse is hovered over the form, then I submit that form, when the user presses the enter key.  But I don't know how to implement this solution.

How can I permit the user to submit the appropriate the form, depending on if the mouse is hovered over that form or if the user has selected a text field or checkbox?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: $(this) will not give you the element under the mouse pointer.

Comment: I gotta tell you, usability (not to mention accessibility) has gone out the window when you have to have one hand on the mouse and the other on the keyboard in order to submit a form...

Answer (score 0):

Add an input `type="submit"` to the form, set it's style to `visibility: hidden`. By default the browser will use the submit button when pressing enter in a field belonging to the same form. No JavaScript required.